# Creating and managing privileged users in Firebase via the console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase I want to create different groups of users (i.e. users, admins etc) for my app. I've created some users via the console but I'm trying to find out if it's possible to assign roles to these users via the console too?

After some reading on their website firebase recommends using [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) which can be encoded within a user's access token. This sounds perfect but the only way I can find to issue such claims is coding an app to access the [admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). Is there any way to achieve the same functionality but via the firebase console instead?

Comment: What kind of roles?

Comment: Roles such as an admin and standard user. I'm wanting to restrict access in my node/express app to users who are admin users for instance.

Comment: No, there is not a way to achieve this through the console. You are correct that the Admin SDK is the way to incorporate custom claims.

Comment: Take a look at the second part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39063833/4916627). Maybe that can give you an idea how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Haven't used firebase database yet. Looks like you've recorded the user's roles in a database with their uid, and defined read/write access rights there?